# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have this really simple code (Glassfish 3.1.2) :

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
```

But the second line throws an Exception :

```
SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/ConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.apache.jsp.room_jsp._jspService(room_jsp.java from :195)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:310)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:218)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
... 34 more
```

Do you have an idea because this 2 lines of code are "standard".
Tkx

Answer (score 1):

You should *create destination* resource and *connection factory* in the **administrative console**.

Answer (score -1):

just lookup for "ConectionFactory" It worked for me that way